# Nested conditionals or some such

Tags: tinybutstrong

I need to do something like:

```
[onshow;if [onload.project.sortBy]='Id';then if [onload.project.sortAscending]=1;then '↓';else '↑']
```

But, perhaps as expected, ↑ is always displayed.

What's the alternative here?

Thank you and be well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `then if` is not support by TBS.

You're trying to perform a `AND` operation between ([onload.project.sortBy]='Id') and ([onload.project.sortAscending]=1) but TBS does not support [logical operators](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/support.php#faq_or).

So here are 3 workarounds:

1) Solution using multiple if/then parameters :

```
[onshow;if '[onload.project.sortBy]'!='Id';then '↑';if [onload.project.sortAscending]=1;then '↓';else '↑']
```

2) Solution by simulating AND with concatenation :

```
[onshow;if '[onload.project.sortBy]-[onload.project.sortAscending]'='Id-1';then '↓';else '↑']
```

3) Solution using custom variable :

```
[onshow;if '[onload.project.sortByIdAscending]'='1';then '↓';else '↑']
```

Comment: That did it. The solution that worked was `[onshow;if [onload.project.sortBy]!='Id';then '';if [onload.project.sortAscending]=1;then '↓';else '↑']`. Thank for the quick reply and a big, big thank you for developing TBS and making available for free. It is a gem. Good karma to you.